# Nlog, Not sending mails to Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

Mail Configuration is Nlog.config file

```
<target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail" smtpServer="smtp.emailsrvr.com" smtpPort="25" smtpUserName="samplemail@samplemail.com" smtpPassword="Password" 
        from="sample-test@intsof.com" to="vinay@sample.com" subject="Hello Mail from Nlog" html="false" encoding="UTF8"/>

<rules>   
  <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="mail"/>
```

Configuration in App.config.

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
 <smtp from="Sample-test@sample.com"  deliveryMethod="Network">
   <network defaultCredentials="true" userName="vinay-test@sample.com" password="Password" host="smtp.emailsrvr.com" port="25"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

If i use the delivery method SpecifiedPickupDirectory and give a local path then its sending mail, but not to outlook.

Comment: Your configuration works for me (with changes the smtp server name, of course).   Can you send mail through this server without using nlog?

Comment: I can also Send mail creating a  Smtp client, but for logging on error level, need Nlog to work.
I can also send mail to my local folder as mentioned above, but not to outlook.

Comment: problem was with my email server it was blocking mails to other domains, I was able to send the mail using my gmail credentials, Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Rex answer your question and accept your answer.

Comment: @Den it was some network prob dude, i was able to send mails using gmail server.

Answer (score 1):

For [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766263/how-do-i-email-errors-logged-with-nlog) question, the accepted answer recommended changing `encoding="UTF8"` to `encoding="UTF-8"`. Try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution as well:

Config:

from="${event-context:item=Sender}"

Logging code:

eventInfo.Properties.Add("Sender", UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress);